# How to read the attached file in http response using ruby?

Tags: ruby, http, httpresponse, attachment

I am new to ruby programming.

I have learning about the file attachments in ruby. In this I was learned about how to attach the file in http request. But I was searched about how read and save the attached file locally in http response. But I did not get anything for this.

**UPDATE :-**

From ruby script I do a http request to the php program.

The source for request is,

```
payload={"id":"1004"}
uri = URI.parse("https://example.com/test.php")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.content_type = "application/json"
request.body = payload.to_json
# request.use_ssl = true
# request.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE 

# logger.info "request body is #{request.body.inspect}"
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, use_ssl: true, verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,:read_timeout => 25 ) { |http|  http.request(request) }
```

From test.php, validated the id if it is valid then in response attached the file contents.

The source for this is,

```
$filename="test.mp3";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($filename);
#    exit;
}
```

**What I want is,  in the ruby script for the http request one response will be received from server. From that response I have extract the file contents and store it in locally.**

I was searched about how to process the file contents in response. But I didn't get anything.

Kindly help me how to do this in ruby.

Comment: What do you have so far? Could you include some example code?

Comment: @Stefan I was updated my question. Kindly look at it